JSON. ToJSONString () method error Java lang. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8192 out of bounds for length 8192
at com.alibaba.fastjson2.JSONWriterUTF16.writeName8Raw(JSONWriterUTF16.java:1719)
at com.alibaba.fastjson2.writer.OWG_8_10_ParcelItemEnt.write(Unknown Source)
at com.alibaba.fastjson2.writer.FieldWriterList.writeListValue(FieldWriterList.java:218)
at com.alibaba.fastjson2.writer.OWG_7_5_ParcelEnt.write(Unknown Source)
at com.alibaba.fastjson2.writer.FieldWriterList.writeListValue(FieldWriterList.java:218)
at com.alibaba.fastjson2.writer.OWG_5_9_PreAlertOrderInfoDto.write(Unknown Source)
at com.alibaba.fastjson2.writer.ObjectWriterImplList.write(ObjectWriterImplList.java:364)
at com.alibaba.fastjson2.JSON.toJSONString(JSON.java:2917)
at com.shaoke.lmp.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl.outboundOrderBag(OrderServiceImpl.java:448)
at com.shaoke.lmp.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl.outboundOrder(OrderServiceImpl.java:354)
at com.shaoke.lmp.controller.OrderController.outboundOrder(OrderController.java:93)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
It hasn't been solved yet

Please provide the relevant code snippet that causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
